# Trying to Create a Fedora VM in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, fedora

I am trying to create a Fedora 30 VM guest in VirtualBox on my Windows host for my Intro to Operating Systems.  My professor has provided me with the Fedora Workstation 30 Live ISO, however, when I try to create the Fedora machine I get the following error:

```
The media check is complete, the result is:  FAIL.
```

How do I fix this?

Here's a screenshot of the attempted install.
[image]

Comment: The screenshot is unreadable. Can you re-upload it or attach directly to the question in better quality? Otherwise, it would be hard to help you.

Comment: Add a better pic. Forgot to label it, so it is the "enter image description here,"  Thanks to anyone who could help.

Comment: Perhaps your Fedora ISO is corrupted.  Try downloading it from a [Fedora mirror](https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/30/Workstation/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-30-1.2.iso) or tell your professor that your ISO seems to be corrupted.  Also note that [Fedora 31](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/) is available if you want to try that.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rick. I was not giving my VM enough memory to run. I fixed it and got it running.

Comment: @dmc3 Perhaps you could write an answer describing the minimum VM memory required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had this problem as well for Fedora 31 on Windows 10 Home, initially 4MB when this error was produced. I increased to 6MB and was able to boot up from the iso.